How to transfer file from someone else's gscloud bucket to google collab/python?
I have access rights to only a part of a google cloud bucket of another person. I can download the files from there to my desktop using terminal or using the bang(!) operator to get the files in my google collab.
gcloud storage cp -r "gs://jk***_storage/openimg_v6_filtered/filtered_images" ./dataImg/

However, I want to download the files one by one as required by my program.
I tried using the google cloud storage library to access the bucket
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import storage

# Instantiates a client
client = storage.Client()

# The name for the new bucket
bucket_name = "jk***_storage/openimg_v6_filtered"
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
# Creates the new bucket
blobs = client.list_blobs(bucket_name)

But, I get following error:
RefreshError: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Status: 404 Response:\nb''", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x7945fa056bf0>)

Any help regarding how to do this is really appreciated.
I am new to google cloud storage, so thanks for the help in advance.

Perform a gcloud auth application-default login and try again.

Check this similar SO by sapo_cosmico which may help to resolve your issue.
